# sql server 2008, set value in default value or binding field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'd like to set default value to a column of a table.
type of the column is date.
i write this function because just need date without time but it doesn't work.

```
DATEFROMPARTS ( year, month, day )
```

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: `DATEFROMPARTS` is a **new** function in SQL Server **2012** and is not available in older versions

Comment: Could you explain a bit what you're trying to do? Set a fixed date as default, or current date, or some combination?

Comment: so what's your suggestion?

Comment: yes it's current date. i want to set the current date to a field of a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always construct a string and then use `cast()` or `convert()`.  I think the easiest way is:

```
select cast(cast((yr*10000 + mon*100 + d) as varchar(8)) as date)
```

This first converts the expression to a number of the form YYYYMMDD.  Then to a string and then to a date.

EDIT:

If you want to set a default value, doesn't this expression work?

```
create table . . . 
    datefield date default '2013-01-01',
```

Comment: first of all thank you but it doesn't work in default value or binding field. give me this error "validating default for field date"